# MVC 4 WebRequest WebResponse caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I am trying to disable the caching on on the the pages. The reason - the page in question should display up to date data on each request and the data is coming from external XML feed.

I am using standard HttpWebRequest HttpWebResponse. All is working fine but I am getting some (I believe) caching issues where by querying XML feed URL directly I am getting more up to date data compared to my Controller/View data which uses the same URL.

XML feed URL is appended with random numbers on each request and Caching was disabled in the controller ([OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]) as well as in the ActionResult, which produces the following:

Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.1
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 13:22:33 GMT
Content-Length: 75285

Request
pretty print
GET /investor-relations/share-price HTTP/1.1
Host: cms.crestnicholson-dev.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: ecos.dt=1470316952533; ASP.NET_SessionId=5lbh4v20kac0boadibjfwedr; IsAgreeToCookiePolicy=true
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

And still outdated/cached data is rendered on the page…

If someone has any ideas/suggestions, It would be greatly appreciated.

Controller code:

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public class InvestorRelationsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SharePrice()
    {
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        return PartialView(GetSharePrice());
    }

    private SharePriceModel GetSharePrice()
    {
        try
        {
            var xml = GetSharePriceXml();
            return ParseSharePrice(xml);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new SharePriceModel() {IsServiceUnavailable = true};
        }
    }

    private SharePriceModel ParseSharePrice(string xml)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(xml, "xml");
        var model = new SharePriceModel();

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(xml));
        var root = doc.DocumentElement;
        model.DateLastUpdated = root.SelectSingleNode("Time").InnerText;
        model.Price = root.SelectSingleNode("CurrentPrice").InnerText;
        model.Change = root.SelectSingleNode("Change").InnerText;
        model.ChangePersentage = root.SelectSingleNode("PercentageChange").InnerText;

        return model;
    }

    private string GetSharePriceXml()
    {
        Uri address = new Uri(SiteConfiguration.SharePriceFeedUrl);

        Random random = new Random();
        string url = address + "?random=" + random.Next();

        // Set a default policy level for the "http:" and "https" schemes.
        HttpRequestCachePolicy policy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default);
        HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = policy;
        HttpRequestCachePolicy noCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

        // Create the web request
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        // Set type to POST
        request.CachePolicy = noCachePolicy;
        request.KeepAlive = false; 
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "private");

        // Get response
        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            // Get the response stream
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                // Console application output
                return reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.